# custom menus based on roles in a pivot page application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, pivot

There is a menu that has all the options. But that needs to be customised based on the role of the use. 
Like:
Student will have access only to the student related stuff
Prof will have access to stuff related to him
Student + Prof will have access to both of them put together.

Is there some way like I can hide a specific grid item and display the rest of them in windows phone 7 pivot pages.

Comment: Please note that Windows-Phone-7 and Windows-mobile are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight, you can hide elements (such as the contents fo a grid) by setting `Visibility` to [Collapsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: With the visiblity property, I'm able to black out the not needed menu items. But the problem here is that it leaves a blank space in the middle of the page. Is there a way to eliminate it, like moving the next grid item programatically in the cs file or anything like it?

Comment: @New developer If you're setting explicit heights for the grid cells but only hiding (collapsing) the content then you'll get that. Either set the height to auto or change the height when you change the visibility of the contents.

Comment: Got it.. thanks.. But I ve built it as a pivot application. Is it possible to control the swipes as well based on the user profile. Like though a particular gird element is now hidden, it is a pivot item and so I'm able to see its contents on a swipe. Is it possible to override this feature?

Comment: @New developer - can you show what you're trying to do. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. I thought you were creating your own context menu using a grid but now you're talking about hiding pivot pages.

Comment: I ve created a pivot application where in based on the user profile, the menu items will change. SAy for instance, Student will have Option A, Option C, Option D; Professor will have Option B, Option C, Option D; Student+Prof will have Options A thro D. I'm able to control the menu by setting the visiblity element. But on swipe, though it is only the Prof,He still continues to have Option A  becoz in the XAML only I have defined all the PivotItems. How to control this is my question. In case of Prof, Option A should not be shown on swipe,same way not optionB if its a student on swipe.

Comment: @New developer can you update the question with code that demonstrates what you're doing and recreates the issue. Sorry-I'm still not clear.

Comment: private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {role = "student";
            if (string.Equals(role, "student"))
            {
OptionB.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
OptionC.Margin = new Thickness(OptionB.Margin.Left, OptionB.Margin.Top - 80, OptionB.Margin.Right, OptionB.Margin.Bottom - 159);
OptionD.Margin = new Thickness(OptionC.Margin.Left, OptionC.Margin.Top +80 , OptionC.Margin.Right, OptionC.Margin.Bottom -359 );
OptionBPivotItem.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

             }

Comment: else if (string.Equals(role, "professor"))
            {
                OptionA.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                OptionB.Margin = new Thickness(OptionA.Margin.Left, OptionA.Margin.Top + 80, OptionA.Margin.Right, OptionA.Margin.Bottom - 159);
                OptionC.Margin = new Thickness(OptionB.Margin.Left, OptionB.Margin.Top + 80, OptionB.Margin.Right, OptionB.Margin.Bottom - 159);
               }

Comment: Here Option B is a Pivot Item and on double click of it, I'm routing it to the Pivot Item. But when the role is a student, I'm hiding the OptionB Menu Item but then on swipe, I still get OptionB as it is a pivot item. How to control this behaviour?